# Pairs of Permutations up to Simultaneous Conjugation

Tags: gr.group-theory, at.algebraic-topology

The conjugacy classes of $S_n$ are the cycle types since if $\tau = (\dots)(\dots)\dots(\dots)$, the conjugation $\tau \mapsto \sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ permutes the labels in the cycles of $\tau$.

Has anyone studied pairs of permutations up to simultaneous conjugation $(\tau_1,\tau_2) \mapsto (\sigma \tau_1 \sigma^{-1}, \sigma \tau_2 \sigma^{-1})$?

These are related to branched covers of a once-punctured torus since $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}-\{ pt\}) = \langle a,b| \text{ no relations }\rangle = \mathbb{F}_2$ we need two generators, $\tau_1, \tau_2$.

Comment: The number of classes can be computed by hand using the friendly GAP and then looked up in the OEIS, which immediately directs to http://oeis.org/A110143, which has a reference (related to branched coverings, in fact)


Comment: (Life is easy these days!)

Comment: They also classify branched covers of a thrice-punctured sphere, which is a little more popular than the one-punctured torus (though each has its special charms.)

Comment: (2 years later) Is there an efficient algorithmic way to check if two pairs of permutations are simultaneously conjugated like this?

Comment: I have posted a related question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162428/the-simultaneous-conjugacy-problem-in-the-symmetric-group-s-n).

Answer (score 4):

Another way to say what's in oeis.org/A110143 is the following. Let
$\lambda$ be a partition of $n$, denoted $\lambda\vdash n$, and let
$z_\lambda$ be the number of permutations in $S_n$ commuting with a
fixed permutation $w$ of cycle type $\lambda$, so
$z_\lambda=1^{m_1}m_1!2^{m_2}m_2!\cdots$, where $\lambda$ has $m_i$
parts equal to $i$. Thus the size of the conjugacy class containing
$w$ is $n!/z_\lambda$.  It is then immediate from the Cauchy-Frobenius
lemma (aka Burnside's lemma) that the number of classes is 
  $$ \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac{n!}{z_\lambda}z_\lambda^2 = 
     \sum_{\lambda\vdash n} z_\lambda. $$
Similarly the number of $k$-tuples of permutations up to simultaneous 
conjugation is $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}z_\lambda^{k-1}$.

Comment: Geoff, I don't follow your reasoning, and $n!p(n)$ is not correct. It is true that $n!p(n)$ is the number of pairs $(u,v)$ of commuting permutations in $S_n$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood your notation. I was thinking the sum was over all permutations in $S_{n},$ not one per conjugacy class. 

Answer (score 2):

As you implicitly point out, you might as well ask about conjugacy classes of subgroups of finite index in $F_2$.

You might be interested in [a famous paper of Marshall Hall Jr](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=1949&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=pubyear&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=hall%2C%20m%2a&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=4&mx-pid=28836),  in which he computed the number of subgroups of a free group of a given index.  It would be a nice exercise to adapt his argument to compute the number of conjugacy classes. (Or perhaps it's done in the paper?  I don't recall, off the top of my head.)

Comment: Is that link correct? 

Comment: I think you mean the following: Marshall Hall Jr., Subgroups of finite index in free groups, Canadian J. Math. 1 (1949). 187-190. 

Comment: do you mean this is a geometric group theory problem?

Comment: John - not exactly (in particular, Marshall Hall wasn't a *geometric* group theorist).  But one can use the methods of geometric group theory to attack it. Incidentally, I don't know what 'this... problem' actually is. Your question is very vague.  It might help if it were more specific.